# Bilingual text in .org mode and xelatex

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-babel

I would like to typeset bilingual (English, Hindi) in emacs .org mode using mangal font available on windows . It has to be exported using xelatex. Kindly explain step by step setup for the same . I would be obliged